# Warning at didReceiveDate method from NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsmutabledata

At following method the compiler is showing a warning.

`buffer` is a `NSMutableData` declared in the header file.

This is the warning message:

```
 Local declaration of 'data' hides instance variable
```

And this is the method which throws the warning:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [buffer appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: Do you have instance variable with name ``data`` of type ``NSData``? Compiler is confused with which ``data`` property should use in ``appendData`` method.

Comment: Yes, but used for another method, you are right....Not seen before.

Comment: Do you agree to put this in answer?

Comment: Yes please, i would be glad selecting your comment as the correct answer.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Done! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is confused with which `data` property should use in `appendData` method. Make sure you only have one property with name `data` in that *scope*.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [buffer appendData:data];
}
```

your didReceiveData data type name and local instance variable name data will conflicted. because both of same name. so far you change the name of local declaration variable like

```
NSMutableData *localData;
```